# Diffrence using pattern search with and without Quotes in python with input fuction

Tags: python, python-3.x

What and why it makes diffrence while using **Patt_Search** as `re.search(Patt_Search, line)` then it works  and `re.search('Patt_Search', line)` don't work , as i ran it and did not seen any error though.. it simply gets out..

Saying that, it works without the quote and don't work with quotes `''`.

The way it works as Below:

```
$ cat Search_string_input.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
File = input("Please Enter the File Name : ")
Patt_Search = input("Please Enter the Pattern you want to search : ")
ldap = open(File, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in ldap:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #if re.search('12:00:16', line) :
    if re.search(Patt_Search, line) :
        print(line)
```

It works as below:

```
$ ./Search_string_input.py
Please Enter the File Name : ldap_data
Please Enter the Pattren you want to serach : 12:00:16
Jan 31 12:00:16 test-1 automount[3432]: bind_ldap_simple: lookup(ldap): Unable to bind to the LDAP server: (default), error Can't contact LDAP server
Jan 31 12:00:16 test-2 automount[3544]: bind_ldap_simple: lookup(ldap): Unable to bind to the LDAP server: (default), error Can't contact LDAP server
Jan 31 12:00:16 hsv-ch02 automount[3006]: bind_ldap_simple: lookup(ldap): Unable to bind to the LDAP server: (default), error Can't contact LDAP server
```

The way it don't works as Below:

```
$ cat Search_string_input.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
File = input("Please Enter the File Name : ")
Patt_Search = input("Please Enter the Pattern you want to search : ")
ldap = open(File, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in ldap:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #if re.search('12:00:16', line) :
    if re.search('Patt_Search', line) :
        print(line)
```

Result is as below, which don't yeild any output and no error though!

```
$ ./Search_string_input.py
Please Enter the File Name : ldap_data
Please Enter the Pattren you want to serach : 06:10:13
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `'Patt_Search'`, it just searches for the string literal `'Patt_Search'`. A string containing a variable name has nothing to do with the variable itself.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and i's thinking the same!

Answer (score 2):

- in the first case you're passing your input `12:00:16`, which is found three times in the file and printed to the screen.
- in the second case you're searching for the string `Patt_Search`, which can't be found in the file `ldap_data`, thus nothing gets printed to the screen.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: if i quote the variable **Patt_search** like `'Patt_search'` with `input` then it did not worked but at the same time if i use this variable **Patt_search**  without quotes with `input` function it works as expected taking the inputs from user.

Comment: `'Patt_search'` has nothing to do with your variable `Patt_search`. It is an completely new string object you've creating through the quotes.

Comment: I agree with  this @dabo, that was my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of this question? The first script apparently works as expected, so why not just use that?

In the second script, `'Patt_Search'` is a literal string, so `re.search('Patt_Search', line)` searches for the string `Patt_Search` in the input line. I'm guessing that your LDAP data file does not contain the string `Patt_Search` anywhere, hence there will not be any matches, and there will be no output nor any errors.

Comment: there is pupose , either i'm unable to make it explicite or something, my intent of asking is , if i quote the variable **Patt_search** like `'Patt_search'` with `input` then it did not worked but at the same time if i use this variable **Patt_search**  without quotes with `input` function it works as expected taking the inputs from user.

Comment: mhawke, secondly .. the though behind this is rather not hard-coding the values in the script i makeit dynamic using `if __name__ == main()` method and call this  into scripts or modules for more granularity.